# Converting Boolean Expression for NAND Gate Implementation - DeMorgan's Law

Tags: circuits, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits

If I have the sum-of-products expression `B~CD + ACD` how would I convert this so it could be implemented using 3-input NAND gates through DeMorgan's Law? Would this not generate the expression: `~(~(B~CD) ^ ~(ACD))`?

It would seem I could implement this and use a 3-input NAND gate with 3-C inputs to act as a NOT gate but this seems wrong.

If this isn't the right place for such a question, let me know and direct me elsewhere if possible, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the basic rule that (a or b) = not (not a and not b), so you use that repeatedly. The first application gave you B~CD + ACD = NAND(~(B~CD), ~(ACD)). You're almost there:

NAND(~(B~CD), ~(ACD)) = NAND (NAND (B, ~C, D), NAND (A, C, D))
 = NAND (NAND (B, NAND (C, C, C), D), NAND (A, C, D))

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have attempted to draw the circuit for this expression using NAND gates. Could you please let me know if it is correct (it's the circuit at the bottom): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By45Ne_MbTIJaGo1WHo2UjJLMHM/view?usp=sharing